# Disable Elementor on specific page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook-woocommerce

I have a plugin that uses the default woocommerce my account shortcode and displays the page only for a specific role. But, I have customized the My Account page using elementor & crocoblock, and the plugin is not working properly. They did give a workaround for this in the documentation, but I can't seem to make it work. This is the code

```
add_filter( 'elementor/frontend/the_content', 'wcb2bsa_disable_elementor_on_sales_agents_area' );
function wcb2bsa_disable_elementor_on_sales_agents_area( $content ) {
    if ( is_account_page() && is_user_logged_in() && wcb2bsa_has_role( get_current_user_id(), 'sales_agent' ) ) {
        return '[woocommerce_my_account]';
    }   
    return $content;
}
```

Is it because the elementor/frontend/the_content part is changed?

Comment: Try replacing `return '[woocommerce_my_account]';` with `echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]'); return;`.

Comment: I have tried this, it did not work. Causing timeout on my site

Comment: Could you report the error you receive? It may be due to other factors and not the function.